# how to update or edit a specific column data in table without affecting other columns in sql table using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datatables, sql-update

how to update specific column in table without affecting other columns sql using C#?
My actual problem is, when i try update or edit a data in sql table it affects the entire row all nulls, what can i do

I have updating from forms with update query

also I am new to StackOverflow

Please help me

thanks in advance

I have tried multiple columns update its working, but what i want is exactly is when I update any specific column, it only should other columns are remain the same data also i can i modify any column without affecting other columns

Here is My code:

```
 private void UpdateUInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Reg.ConnectionString = @"Data Source = SRINIVASG-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = WMSConnect; Integrated Security = True";//This is a connection string, is used to connect a database
            Reg.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter DelSUser = new SqlDataAdapter("UPDATE WMSRegform SET Name = '"+ FNameBox.Text +"', UserName = '"+ UNameBox.Text +"', MailAddr ='"+ MailBox.Text + "' , Paswrd = '" + PwdBox.Text + "', Contactinfo ='" + Contactinfo.Text + "'WHERE EmpID = " + EmpolyeeCode.Text +";", Reg);//This is a sql adapter class and it helps us to populate the data from Sql to c# like a bridge
            DataTable UpdUs = new DataTable();//I have create a datatable, it used populate a data
            DelSUser.Fill(UpdUs);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = UpdUs;
            Reg.Close();

            if (UpdUs.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Mention User Has Been Updated Succesfully");

                clear();
            }
```

Comment: First, I'd recommend using parameters and not a string concatenation. It's open to injection, and also parameters are a lot easier to type and validate. Second, SQL is only going to update the columns that you tell it to update for the most part. So unless you've got a trigger on the table, or maybe constraints, then the problem is most likely that *you* are sending the NULLs. It will be hard to say without your table structure and sample data.

Comment: And stop storing passwords in plain text. It is borderline criminal activity. This information should be salted and hashed.

Comment: You could add a check to see if your variable (Ex: `FName.Text`) is empty before adding it to your update sql. You don't want to pass the empty/null value to SQL because it IS a valid value so it will be accepted.